# How to simulate keydown events using win32api in python?

Tags: python, windows, keyboard, keyboard-events, keydown

Specifically using the keybd_event() function? Do I have to use a while loop to "hold down" the key, or is there a proper way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

`SendInput` is better than `keybd_event` but either way, you tell the function when a key is pressed and call it again to release a key, you don't have to keep calling the function to keep the key pressed.

If possible, consider using UI Automation instead of faking input.